# I can't figure out which lego model these doors came from

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I've been searching for 5 days, but I can't figure out or find this type of door.  I am sure it's from year 2000 upwards because I bought this from a mother whose child is all grown up, thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED LISTING THE CORRECT STOCKADE DOOR - Thanks to TheBrickBlogger**

The two left doors are [30223 - Door 1x5x7 1/2 Stockade](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30223&in=S) and they appear in 11 sets.

[image]

The middle one on your picture seems to be Reddish Brown, which is in only 1 set, [7036 - Dwarves' Mine](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=7036-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), exactly decorated the way you have the door (with the pyramid shape in Pearl Gold on top).

[image: http://img.bricklink.com/SL/7036-1.jpg]

The left one is the same door in black; there are [5 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30223&in=S) with this door. None of the doors visible on the pictures in Bricklink is exactly as you have it - so likely it was used by the previous owner in a MOC, unless it is one of the not-clearly-visible doors in [7419 - Dragon Fortress](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=7419-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), which has 4 of these doors in the set (all other sets have 2).

[image]

None of the sets that these doors contain the net, but out of the [46 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=71155&in=S) with a [71155 - String, Net 10x10 square](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=71155#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) there is only one where the net is folded double and squeezed between the 1x4 plates on your picture.

[image]

This particular set is [7048 - Troll Warship](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=7048-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) and you see the net being used in exactly the same way to trap a minifig, so my best bet is that this net comes from this set.

[image]

The sets I describe here are all from the period 2003-2008, so that would have been the previous owner's key years of LEGO collecting.

Comment: The door is actually incorrect. The OP's picture shows a smaller version than the one you listed. The larger door - as you correctly mentioned - doesn't come in black. The smaller door however does. You can also clearly distinguish the two doors from the different mold around the hinges. The smaller door was retired in 2008. See here: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30223&in=S

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger - wow, somehow I missed that door in my search. Will update my answer with credits to you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Great detective work on figuring out which sets they are likely from! :)